# how to merge two Add Column codes in same step?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have the code below that

1. Searches the concatenation of the numeric parts in column `STR` of table `Source` within column `VAL2` of table `Codes`. For example, for string `abc.sec712.fir001.wpqdata`, looks for `712001` in column `VAL2`. (CustomOUT1)
2. Searches the best match for values in column `NUM` of table `Source` within column `VAL1` of table `Codes`. (Step `CustomOUT2)

These two steps are done separated using Table.AddColumn() in step `CustomOUT1` and `CustomOUT2`.

Since both steps are using Table.AddColumn(), I'd like to join the logic of both steps in a single `Table.AddColumn()` step.

How can I do this?

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ZY3LCsIwEEX/JesSMsl0kiwFobZqK4WsQhexVXDnC/x9UyVqEAbu5XCY6z1bbGtWMCBCjMmGwrO+72JVwmqjbIKNa2cokQx8YLVysSJaW2qT4LrbxErKAonEdq+X8cJ+5LfDqEHy4+kqBPDH+TKFe/hZ/mqqpFkDEJlWt1Wu4VvDXFs2LtOk+B8dng==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [TRS = _t, NUM = _t, STR = _t]),

    Codes = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("XZDNjoMwDITfhXMPdn4cfOymqEUNzQqCWhX1/V9jbbPsYU8gT+absbetq6W0oXanLjKmJN/kCcB3n9PWLfM8LYvMOLmY0MlfcBEgmTrnXK+zzDwQq9OBA0DTxvM5P0eZoaPgfNRXFPsABzc/lYtEIbByfQw97eo85jkrNwJ5APVK9kFelGzemCAhqRelABydct07/a80lHKvg0ouUI8sDtVJXphepykXPQT2jplRXyYAcKbmda0t25k8s3UKIu7WYV0vqOjgKREIQNH0F/0ehq/81jtyiFFzzbuTH7LP/WG5xERgxyDE34Vaa5MtFJHJsD0Amba+Xt9tNU321MJOC++Zt1Ku7SYz8oxkVaU8Rov9/AA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [CODE = _t, VAL1 = _t, VAL2 = _t]),

    CustomOUT1
      = Table.AddColumn(
        Source,
        "OUT1",
        (i) =>
          try
            Table.SelectRows(
              Codes,
              each Text.Middle(i[STR],7,3) & Text.Middle(i[STR],14,3) = [VAL2]
            )[CODE]{0}
          otherwise
            "NOT FOUND"
     ,type text ),


  CustomOUT2 = Table.AddColumn(
  CustomOUT1,
  "OUT2",
  each
    if [NUM] = "" then
      null
    else  
      let
        t = Table.AddIndexColumn(
          Table.SelectRows(
            Codes,
            (x) =>
              let
                s = List.Sort({x[VAL1], [NUM]}, each Text.Length(_))
              in
                Text.StartsWith(s{1}, s{0})
          ),
          "Index"
        )
      in
        if Table.RowCount(t) > 0 then
          Table.First(
            Table.Sort(
              t,
              (y) =>
                Number.BitwiseShiftLeft(
                  Number.Abs(Text.Length([NUM]) - Text.Length(y[VAL1])),
                  32
                )
                  + y[Index]
            )
          )[CODE]
        else
          "NOT FOUND"
  ,type text)
in
    CustomOUT2
```

**Tables Source and Codes**
[image]

**Table with both outputs from two AddColumn Steps**
[image]

**Desired output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest?

```
....
 CustomOUT2 = Table.AddColumn(
  CustomOUT1,
  "OUT",
  each
    if [NUM] = "" then
      [OUT1]
...
```

then right click and remove column OUT1

```
let Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ZY3LCsIwEEX/JesSMsl0kiwFobZqK4WsQhexVXDnC/x9UyVqEAbu5XCY6z1bbGtWMCBCjMmGwrO+72JVwmqjbIKNa2cokQx8YLVysSJaW2qT4LrbxErKAonEdq+X8cJ+5LfDqEHy4+kqBPDH+TKFe/hZ/mqqpFkDEJlWt1Wu4VvDXFs2LtOk+B8dng==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [TRS = _t, NUM = _t, STR = _t]),

Codes = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("XZDNjoMwDITfhXMPdn4cfOymqEUNzQqCWhX1/V9jbbPsYU8gT+absbetq6W0oXanLjKmJN/kCcB3n9PWLfM8LYvMOLmY0MlfcBEgmTrnXK+zzDwQq9OBA0DTxvM5P0eZoaPgfNRXFPsABzc/lYtEIbByfQw97eo85jkrNwJ5APVK9kFelGzemCAhqRelABydct07/a80lHKvg0ouUI8sDtVJXphepykXPQT2jplRXyYAcKbmda0t25k8s3UKIu7WYV0vqOjgKREIQNH0F/0ehq/81jtyiFFzzbuTH7LP/WG5xERgxyDE34Vaa5MtFJHJsD0Amba+Xt9tNU321MJOC++Zt1Ku7SYz8oxkVaU8Rov9/AA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [CODE = _t, VAL1 = _t, VAL2 = _t]),

CustomOUT1
  = Table.AddColumn(
    Source,
    "OUT1",
    (i) =>
      try
        Table.SelectRows(
          Codes,
          each Text.Middle(i[STR],7,3) & Text.Middle(i[STR],14,3) = [VAL2]
        )[CODE]{0}
      otherwise
        "NOT FOUND"
 ,type text ),


CustomOUT2 = Table.AddColumn(
CustomOUT1,
"OUT",
each
if [NUM] = "" then
  [OUT1]
else  
  let
    t = Table.AddIndexColumn(
      Table.SelectRows(
        Codes,
        (x) =>
          let
            s = List.Sort({x[VAL1], [NUM]}, each Text.Length(_))
          in
            Text.StartsWith(s{1}, s{0})
      ),
      "Index"
    )
  in
    if Table.RowCount(t) > 0 then
      Table.First(
        Table.Sort(
          t,
          (y) =>
            Number.BitwiseShiftLeft(
              Number.Abs(Text.Length([NUM]) - Text.Length(y[VAL1])),
              32
            )
              + y[Index]
        )
      )[CODE]
    else
      "NOT FOUND"
,type text),
  #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(CustomOUT2,{"OUT1"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. You have seen with more experienced eyes :) and found an easier way.